Similarity measure for sparse, ordered, binary vectors, with more weighting to True values
I have two sparse, ordered, binary vectors. The size of the vectors is around ~100.
I am under the impression that cosine similarity is useful for sparse, ordered, binary vectors. For my purposes, it is good, BUT not exactly what I am looking for.
Say I have two sets of pairs of vectors: A =: {{0,0,0}, {0,0,0}} and B =: {{1,1,1}, {1,1,1}}. The cosine similarity between (A1, A2) and (B1, B2) are the same since both pairs are identical HOWEVER, I would like a measure that weighs more to B, because it has more observations of 1's.
I can create a rudimentary measure by summing up the amount of 1's in the vector, then multiplying this by the cosine similarity.
I was just curious if there was a more thought-out (possibly accurate) method?
